# Laravel 5.1 Socialite 2.0 issue with Bitbucket driver - Required Repository?

Tags: laravel, oauth, bitbucket

I'm creating an application in Laravel 5.0 and I want implement socialite 2.0 as OAuth package.
I tried this package for **GitHub, Google, Linked In** and everything is working fine. But after configuring my **Bitbucket** account and granting **permission** to read Email scope, I'm receiving this error:

```
Received error [{"error": {"message": "Your credentials lack one or more required privilege scopes.", "detail": {"granted": ["account"], "required": ["repository"]}}}] with status code [403] when retrieving token credentials.
```

After editing my consumer account in Bitbucket and adding **Read Repository Permission**, everything going to be fine except receiving **Null Emails**.

First, I don't want to prompt my users to allow to access their repositories, I don't need them and I don't want to scare my clients.

Second, how can I solve null email issue?

Comment: Dear Bitbucket, Y U NO PROVIDE EMAIL IN API?? D:

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain. User authentication via third-party without the user email is, to say the least, useless. In the very extreme, it might be dangerous and unsafe to ask for the user to input an email.

Thus, I've created a small fork of the original Bitbucket connector (from the League Of Extraordinary Packages): https://github.com/igorsantos07/oauth1-client

The best way to retrieve the user email and other missing info (such as location) was upgrading to API 2.0, what means repositories are not retrieved anymore. It might be a breaking change for some users, but I guess for many others it will actually be less data to be downloaded.

To install that fork into your project, add/merge the following to your `composer.json`:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/igorsantos07/oauth1-client"
    }
]
```

Then, you should `composer require league/oauth1-client:dev-master`. It will download the fork's master branch, with the said Bitbucket upgrades.

> **Note:** I still have nooooo idea why Bitbucket asks for *repository* permissions to retrieve user emails. Go figure...

Comment: Upvote for your cool work, but asking for repository permission is like a issue for this authentication. I think i should remove bitbucket for my OAuth list. Downvote for bitbucket

Comment: Indeed, if that feel unsecure (too much info to share) just for a simple authentication, it's better for your users sanity if Bitbucket authentication is not provided.
Meanwhile, as this is not solvable without Bitbucket intervention in their API and this answer indeed solves the "null email issue", wouldn't it deserve a "correct answer" check? :)

Answer (score 0):

In your users migration you will need to set email up as being able to add an account without there being an email.

change:

```
$table->string('provider')->default('myapp');
```

to:

```
$table->string('provider')->default('myapp')->nullable();
```

Comment: You're removing question, not solving it. But thank you, this can be an alternative way to overcome this issue, +1 for you. However I need a valid email and I have to solve this problem in BitBucket side.